# How to show that there is a natural isomorphism of rings $k\left(s\right)\otimes_{k}k\left(t\right)=S^{-1}\left(k\left(s\right)\left[t\right]\right)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

Let $k$ be a field, $s$ and $t$ two indeterminates over $k$.

Let $S$ be the set of non-zero elements of $k\left[t\right]$.

How can it be shown that there is a natural isomorphism of rings $k\left(s\right)\otimes_{k}k\left(t\right)=S^{-1}\left(k\left(s\right)\left[t\right]\right)$?

This seems to be quite trivial, but I'm not sure how can it be proved rigorously.

Edit:

Does this look like a correct and complete solution?

Let $a\in k\left(s\right),b=\frac{b_{1}}{b_{2}}\in k\left(t\right)
 $, where $b_{1}\in k\left[t\right]$ and $b_{2}\in S$.
Then a natural isomorphism $\phi:k\left(s\right)\otimes_{k}k\left(t\right)\leftrightarrow S^{-1}\left(k\left(s\right)\left[t\right]\right)$ can be defined as 
$$
a\otimes_{k}\frac{b_{1}}{b_{2}}\leftrightarrow b_{2}^{-1}\left(ab_{1}\right)
$$

Comment: $k(s)=S^{-1}k[s]$, and $k(t)=T^{-1}k[t]$, where $S=k[s]-\{0\}$ and $T=k[t]-\{0\}$. So, $k(s)\otimes_k k(t)=(ST)^{-1}k[s,t]$.

Comment: Well said, @Alex!

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Thanks :)

Comment: By the way, @Alex's answer is better than than the proposed formula because it is **symmetric** in $s,t$ while the formula $S^{-1}\left(k\left(s\right)\left[t\right]\right)$ is not .

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Yes, but $S^{-1}\left(k\left(s\right)\left[t\right]\right)$ is part of the problem statement, and it is not obvious to me how the tensor product was transformed to the r.h.s. part of equation.

Comment: Dear Jake: I didn't want to criticize you personally, since you are certainly entitled to ask a question which results from your specific context. I just wanted to emphasize  that, absent such a specific context, a symmetric formula is more natural.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Yes, indeed.

Comment: There is a beautiful discussion of Jake's problem on page 29 of [this nice handout](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/linmultialg/tensorprod2.pdf) by  Keith  Conrad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to reinvent the wheel.

If $A,B$ are any commutative $R$-algebras and $S \subseteq B$ is a multiplicative system, then

$A \otimes_R (S^{-1} B) = S^{-1} (A \otimes_R B).$

In fact, $A \otimes_R (S^{-1} B) = A \otimes_R (B \otimes_R S^{-1} R) = (A \otimes_R B) \otimes_R S^{-1} R = S^{-1} (A \otimes_R B)$.

Apply this to $B=R[t]$.